# How to set Clock time and date to be always today 11 PM?

Tags: java, spring

```
@Spy
Clock clock = Clock.fixed(Instant.parse(
        "2021-08-28T08:00:42.00Z"), ZoneId.of("Europe/Kiev"));
```

Time set as needed, but the date is static. I want it to be today for testing ( or be absent at all ).
How can this be done?

P.S. The day the code is executed the date must always reflect the current day but the time must always be 11 pm

Comment: By *today*, can I assume that you mean the day the code is run? Not August 29, 2021?

Comment: @OleV.V. there was a mistake in code, I've changed it. By today I mean 29.08, tomorrow I want it to be 30.08 and so on.

Comment: To clarify further, do you mean the _day_ the code is executed the _date_ must always reflect the current day but the time must always be 11 pm

Comment: @D-Dᴙum Yes, that is what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private static final ZoneId ZONE = ZoneId.of("Europe/Kiev");
private static final LocalDate TODAY = LocalDate.now(ZONE);
private static final LocalTime TIME = LocalTime.of(23, 0); // 11 PM
private static final Instant fixedInstant
        = TODAY.atTime(TIME).atZone(ZONE).toInstant();

Clock clock = Clock.fixed(fixedInstant, ZONE);
```

We can try it out:

```
    System.out.println(ZonedDateTime.now(clock));
```

Output:

> 2021-08-29T23:00+03:00[Europe/Kiev]